# Block Microservice Instance from registering with Eureka Service Discovery

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

Is there a way via configuration to blacklist specific ip addresses from registering as microservices with Spring Eureka cloud discovery?  It seems that each time I restart my discovery service an unrecognized ip instance is registering as a microservice.  From the attached image I would expect that only a single instance be present rather than the two shown.

Currently the application.yml file is configured as follows:

```
---
# This default profile is used when running a single instance completely standalone:
#spring:
#  profiles: default
server:
  port: 8010  
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eurekahost 
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  user:
    name: user # login username
    password: password
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not my ideal solution since I prefer to do this via configuration, I found that I can de-register the service via Eureka's REST API.

[image]